# Getting weird popup in IE while using ADAL.js for login to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

I am using ADAL.js for log-in to Azure. But getting this weird popup, in which I have to explicitly select **Continue to Website**. How could I avoid this?
[image]

**How could I avoid this?**

Comment: Are you getting this error before logging in or after?

Comment: For which domain do you get this message? Are you able to log in successfuly? You'll need to give us a bit more info to be able to help you.

Comment: I am using `config = {
        clientId:<GUID>,
        callback: callbackLogin,
        popUp: true
    };
    authContext = new AuthenticationContext(config); authContext.login()` And I am using my Microsoft account to login. My account is of fareast domain in Microsoft. Yes, I am able to log-in successfully.

Comment: @GauravMantri I am getting this error before entering the credential. After pressing the continue button there is no issue.

Answer (score 0):

This popup typically means the site certificate isn't trusted by your client. Verify that the site's certificate was issued by a trusted issuer. If yes, download and copy the public portion of the cert (.cer) from the site and import into your local machine account's trusted store and that should hopefully resolve your issue.